# how to filter values using Regex - Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm a newbie at using Regex; I have some values that I want to filter using Java and Regex.

- 1000
- 1200
- 1300
- 1310
- 1320
- 1330
- 1400
- 1410
- 1420
- 1430
- 2000

The result should be:

1. to show the values that have only 0 as the last character. ex(1310, 1320, 1330, 1410, 1420, 1430)
2. to show the values that have only 00 as the last 2 characters. ex(1200, 1300, 1400)
3. to show the values that have only 000 as the last 3 characters. ex(1000, 2000)

Comment: So what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: i tried this java code to filter by 0 but it doesn't work .

Comment: BTW, it looks like it can be done without regex, but with just `%` operator. This is in case it's the only task.

Comment: could you explain more please

Comment: If all of your input is just numbers and you need to check if they end with zero, you can can do this:
`1-to show the values that have only 0 as last character. ex(1410 , 1420,1430, 1310, 1320 , 1330)` 
check if `number % 10 == 0 && number % 100 != 0`                                                    
`2-to show the values that have only 00 as last character. ex(1400 , 1300,1200) ` 
check if `number % 100 == 0 && number % 1000 != 0`
etc

Comment: i did understand your proposition but i don't know how to do it in java , could you please give me an example. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`String#endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29). It's likely to provide a simpler solution than using regex. (@dty - The `%` only works if the values are stored in `int` variables to begin with. If they're `String` values, trying to use `%` just complicates the problem.)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Ted Hopp, i tried using  endsWith("0") , but it gives me all the numbers that finishes with 0 . (ex 1420, 1400, .....) and my goal is to show only (1420,1410,...).

Comment: @TedHopp - of course, there was an implicit implication that Integer.parseInt() would be used in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String txt=key;

String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
String re2="(0)";   // Any Single Character 1

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
if (m.find())
{

   System.out.println(key+"  "+value);
}
```

Comment: Key is an array containing these values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list in an array of strings, you could simply loop over the list and test each string with Pattern and Matcher from [java.util.regx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

```
    ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList();
    numberList.add("1230");
    numberList.add("1004");
    numberList.add("1000");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0");
    for (int x = 0; x < numberList.size(); x++) {
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(numberList.get(x));
         int count = 0;
         while (matcher.find()) {
              count++;
         }
         if (count == 1) {
             System.out.print(numberList.get(x) + " has one 0\n");
         }
         if (count == 2) {
             System.out.print(numberList.get(x) + " has two 0s\n");
         }
         if (count == 3) {
             System.out.print(numberList.get(x) + " has three 0s\n");
         }
    }
```

Output:

```
 1230 has one 0
 1004 has two 0s
 1000 has three 0s
```

Comment: @J.Simpa Edited and tested.

Answer (score 0):

the Regex Solution works :) ;  I've also found an other solution without using Regex:

```
if(key.endsWith("0") && !key.contains("00") && !key.contains("000")  )
```

Thanks to every one.

Comment: That will not work as you expect for longer strings that might end in a "0" and still contain "00", such as "10010". Also, the test for "000" is unnecessary. if `key` doesn't contain "00", it certainly doesn't contain "000".

Comment: yes, you are right, i didn't think of it, but in my case, i don't expect a number like 10010, 0's will gonna be always on the left, not in the middle . ex : 1400,1420. .. thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using a regex for this. Instead, I would recommend simply counting the number of trailing zeroes using a loop:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1000", "1200", "1300", "1310", ... );
for (String item : items) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = item.length() - 1; i >= 0 && item.charAt(i) == '0'; --i) {
        count++;
    }
    // item has "count" trailing zeroes
}
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest using [`String#endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-). But with either a regex or using `endsWith()`, since all strings that end in "00" also end in "0", you're going to have to be a little clever about your tests. So, for instance, to allow "1420" but not "1400", you could use:

```
if (item.endsWith("0") && !item.endsWith("00")) {
    // item ends with exactly one 0
}
```

Alternatively (and better, in my opinion), you can use a series of `if..else` conditions, in descending order of trailing zero lengths:

```
if (item.endsWith("000")) {
    // item ends with (at least) three zeroes
} else if (item.endsWith("00")) {
    // item ends with exactly two zeroes
} else if (item.endsWith("0")) {
    // item ends with exactly one zero
} else {
    // item does not end in a zero
}
```

If you need to output the items in order of the number of trailing zeroes, you will need to sort them into bins and process the results in a later step. Something like this:

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> two = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> three = new ArrayList<>();

for (String item : items) {
    if (item.endsWith("000")) {
        three.add(item);
    } else if (item.endsWith("00")) {
        two.add(item);
    } else if (item.endsWith("0")) {
        one.add(item);
    }
}

// now process the results:
System.out.print("Items with one trailing zero: ");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", one);
System.out.print("Items with two trailing zeroes: ");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", two);
System.out.print("Items with three or more trailing zeroes: ");
System.out.println(String.join(", ", three);
```

(The method [`String#join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) is new to Java 1.8. If you are using earlier versions of Java, you'll need to create a string representation in a different way.)

If you are dead set on using a regex anyway, you should create a `Matcher` from a `Pattern` that matches trailing zeroes and examine the length of the matched character sequence if a match is found:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("0+$"); // match one or more trailing zeroes
for (String item : items) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(item);
    if (m.find()) {
        int trailingZeroCount = m.group().length();
        // process accordingly
    }
}
```